# Testing for player's height (Y level)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been trying to figure out to test for a player's height in the world. I specifically want to be able to test if they are at or above a certain level or below a certain level. I am in 1.20.1.

Here's one of the commands I have been playing with:

```
/effect give @a[y=200] minecraft:blindness 1 1 true
```

I want to get blindness if my Y level is 200 with this one.

How would I test for y level and inlcude arguments like: =, <, >, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

To start, write these 2 commands out in chat,

```
/scoreboard objectives add YLevel dummy
```

and

```
/scoreboard players set YLevel YLevel [Your Lower Bound Number]
```

after that use a repeating command block and a chain command block, with both command blocks on always active. In the repeating command block put this command in,

```
execute as @a at @s store result score @s YLevel run data get entity @s Pos[1] 1
```

and in the chain command block put,

```
execute as @a if score @s YLevel >= YLevel YLevel run [whatever command you want to run]
```

and that is it, Hope this helps.